# Convert python nested JSON-like data to dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, nested

My records looks like this and I need to write it to a csv file:

```
my_data={"data":[{"id":"xyz","type":"book","attributes":{"doc_type":"article","action":"cut"}}]}
```

which looks like json, but the next record starts with `"data"` and not `"data1"` which forces me to read each record separately. Then, I convert it to a dict using `eval()`, to iterate thru keys and values for a certain path to get to the values I need. Then, I generate a list of keys and values based on the keys I need. Then, a `pd.dataframe()` converts that list into a dataframe which I know how to convert to csv. My code that works is below. But I am sure there are better ways to do this. Mine scales poorly. Thx.

```
counter=1
k=[]
v=[]
res=[]
m=0
for line in f2:
    jline=eval(line)
counter +=1
for items in jline:
    k.append(jline[u'data'][0].keys())
    v.append(jline[u'data'][0].values())
print 'keys are:', k
i=0
j=0
while i <3 :
    while j <3:
        if k[i][j]==u'id':
            res.append(v[i][j])
        j += 1    
    i += 1
#res is my result set
del k[:]
del v[:]
```

Comment: It looks like it may be completely unnecessary for you to use the `'data'` key. Because of how dictionaries work, you cannot have `data` map to more than one value. If you just use a list, you can just rely on positional indices and the dataframe can index them for you

Comment: I agree with you but I don't have any control on how the data is published. My code is one way of extracting the data. How would you go about coding what you described?

Answer (score 0):

Changing my_data to be:

```
my_data = [{"id":"xyz","type":"book","attributes":{"doc_type":"article","action":"cut"}}, # Data One
{"id":"xyz2","type":"book","attributes":{"doc_type":"article","action":"cut"}}, # Data Two
{"id":"xyz3","type":"book","attributes":{"doc_type":"article","action":"cut"}}] # Data Three
```

You can dump this directly into a dataframe as so:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
```

It's not clear what your data path would be, but if you are looking for specific combinations of `id`, `type`, etc. You could explicitly search

```
def find_my_way(data, pattern):

    # pattern = {'id':'someid', 'type':'sometype'...}
    res = []
    for row in data:
        if row.get('id') == pattern.get('id'):
            res.append(row)
    return row


mydf = pd.DataFrame(find_my_way(mydata, pattern))
```

EDIT:

Without going into how the api works, in pseudo-code, you'll want to do something like the following:

```
my_objects = []
calls = 0
while calls < maximum:

    my_data = call_the_api(params)

    data = my_data.get('data')

    if not data:
        calls+=1
        continue

    # Api calls to single objects usually return a dictionary, to group objects they return lists. This handles both cases
    if isinstance(data, list):
        my_objects = [*data, *my_objects]

    elif isinstance(data, {}):
        my_objects = [{**data}, *my_objects]

# This will unpack the data response into a list that you can then load into a DataFrame with the attributes from the api as the columns

df = pd.DataFrame(my_objects)
```

Assuming your data from the api looks like:

```
"""
 {
 "links": {},
 "meta": {},
 "data": {
    "type": "FactivaOrganizationsProfile",
    "id": "Goog",
    "attributes": {
      "key_executives": {
        "source_provider": [
          {
            "code": "FACSET",
            "descriptor": "FactSet Research Systems Inc.",
            "primary": true
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "people": {
        "data": {
            "type": "people",
            "id": "39961704"
          }
      }
    }
  },
 "included": {}
 }
 """
```

per the documentation, which is why I'm using `my_data.get('data')`.

That should get you all of the data (unfiltered) into a DataFrame

Saving the `DataFrame` for the last bit is a bit more memory friendly

Comment: Two issues: 1. It looks like you modified my data set and removed '{"data": ...}'. How can I do this flattening by code? 2. My objective is not searching. I'd like to extract the data exhaustively and write to csv. How would you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "extract the data exhaustively", do you just want all of the data into a csv without filtering?

I did remove 'data', since you want that key to point to multiple values, per "but the next record starts with "data" and not "data1" ." Unless I misunderstood, and you want different keys

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear. Yes, I want all the data without filtering to be written into a csv. Each record has an id. I would like a csv with one row per record and columns loaded with the values. The keys will be my column headers. The source of the data is from here: https://github.com/dowjones/dj-dna-streams-python